# Displaying combined data values in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, labeling, parcel

I've got some data in an attributes table and I would like to know how I can combine them in order to get an unique value in the map.

For instance,

- Attribute: Type
- Value: Street

Those values I want to represent in the following format: **Type / Street**

Comment: Are you referring to labeling features, or actually symbolizing, or colorizing the features based on multiple attributes?

Comment: I referred labeling features. I want to plot out a parcel numbers in format: 360/6

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want to do is write an expression for your label instead of simply choosing a "Label" field.
On the Label tab of the Layer Properties:
[image]

Choose the "Expression" button:
[image]

Here, you can see that I have entered the following: "Parcel Number = " & [APN]
The first part of this:  "Parcel Number = ", is simply a text string
The second part:  [APN], refers to an attribute field, and will pull the value from it.

If you click on the "Verify" button, it will show you how this expression evaluates.
[image]

This can be used to combine different text strings and attribute fields, as well as write conditional expressions.  Please see the help section on [Essential Labeling Concepts](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Essential_labeling_concepts/00s80000000t000000/).

There are many ways of configuring labels in ArcMap, and the help sections do a good job of describing them and providing examples.

Answer (score 1):

Get Spatial's answer above is probably the preferred method, in that it directly addresses labeling. If, however, you have some reason for wanting this concatenated string of two fields to be persistent in your data source, you could add a new add a field to your table and create the value there and use the new field as your label.

Open the table.
Select Add Field. Set the field type to Text
Right click on the header for the new field in the table and select Field Calculator
For your example above the field expression is
[Type] & "/" & [Street]

Comment: Thanks a lot for those two answers! I helps me a lot! Both are useful, but actually my point was exactly in the second answer. And I was surprised that i didn t get it before. Adding the new field is of course the easiest way! :) THANKS!